# CABasicAnimation doesn't work after a segue

Tags: xcode, segue, cabasicanimation, quartz-core

I am following a maze tutorial ([link](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-game-tutorial-maze-part-1/)) in which I animate an UIImageView named ghost1 thanks to the following code (the code is in the viewDidLoad: method of the file ViewController.h):

```
CGPoint origin1 = self.ghost1.center;
CGPoint target1 = CGPointMake(self.ghost1.center.x, self.ghost1.center.y-124);

CABasicAnimation *bounce1 = [CABasicAnimation         

animationWithKeyPath:@"position.y"];
bounce1.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:origin1.y];
bounce1.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:target1.y];
bounce1.duration = 2;
bounce1.autoreverses = YES;
bounce1.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;

[self.ghost1.layer addAnimation:bounce1 forKey:@"position"];
```

At this point it works well. Now, I want to add a new initial view to the application (in order to first display a menu and not directly the game) and to launch the game when I press a "start" button in this new view.

I added the button and a segue of type "show". When I press the button, 
the game is displayed but the animation does not work.

Do you know why and how I can correct that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I just found a solution here: [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=9985)

I just had to move the code from viewDidLoad: to viewDidAppear:. I don't exactly understand why but it works.